# FPDF Problema al descargar y redireccionar

Tags: php, mvc, fpdf

compañeros
tengo este pequeño problema al colocar el header para redireccionar a otra página, no me descarga el PDF, que creen que pueda estar fallando [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Código como texto, por favor. De paso, cuéntanos si sale algún error en la consola del navegador o en los logs de PHP cuando intentas descargar el PDF. Todo esto yendo a [edit] la pregunta

Comment: Cuando estás enviando el PDF representa que ya estás enviando datos, por lo tanto no puedes agregar más cabeceras header a la salida y por eso no te funciona. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] (sobretodo ese) para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio y el porque no nos sirven las imágenes de código, sino que queremos el código en modo texto.